# Rails 4 ActiveRecord::Relation ArgumentError just doesn't make sense

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, relation, squeel

This is a rather simple Rails 4 situation.  Model Intranet has_many activities.  Activities exists with sufficient records for several intranets.  Current_intranet.activities.size returns 69 records.  However, whenever I try to access any of the records, I receive "output error: `<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)"` even though I'm not passing any arguments.  All of the following fail with that error.

```
Current_intranet.activities.first
Activity.where(intranet_id: 1).first
Activity.where(:intranet_id => 1).first
Activity.where{intranet_id.eq 1}.first
All of the above with [0] instead of first
```

There is no problem with any other models
I'd appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks in advance.

There are no defined scopes.  The code is:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_capitalized

  # activities created during intranet creation.  
  DEFAULT_ACTIVITIES = { 'Document Preparation' => 'general income', 'No Charge' => 'general income'}

  # static activity names that can not be deleted.
  STATIC_ACTIVITY_NAMES = [ 'Document Preparation','No Charge']

  before_destroy :check_if_used
  before_destroy :cannot_delete_static_activities

  belongs_to :created_by_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "created_by"
  belongs_to :updated_by_user, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => "updated_by"

  belongs_to :intranet
  belongs_to :chart_of_account  

  has_many :activity_rates, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :event_type
  has_many :billings do 
    def find_by_name(name)
      (find :all, :conditions => ["activity.name = ?",name])
    end
  end

  has_many :document_templates, :foreign_key => "billing_activity_id"

  validates_presence_of :intranet_id, :name, :chart_of_account_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, :scope => :intranet_id
```

Comment: Is `Current_intranet` an instance variable, or is that a constant / class?

Comment: What are you trying to do with this line? `Activity.where{intranet_id.eq 1}.first`  That syntax looks incorrect.

Comment: It was in console.  I'm just trying to access the data in the first record.. or any record for that matter.  A .each fails as well.  As to the syntax, that's squeal. I'm pretty sure it's correct.

Comment: Can you post the `Activity` model?

Comment: it is predominantly Rails 2 code that I'm converting to 4.  I can't seem to post the code as it's longer than the character limit.

Comment: Just post the associations and any scopes

Comment: @user2000664 Not in the comments; just edit the original question and add it in there. Code isn't formatted (and becomes pretty unreadable) in the comments.

Comment: Well, I've stumbled on some progress, but I don't understand the underlying issue.  Activity.where(intranet_id: 1).first still does not work, but if I add the field name as a symbol, it does.  IOW Activity.where(intranet_id: 1).first[:name] properly returns the name from the first record, while Activity.where(intranet_id: 1).first.name continues to return the same error

Comment: Does something like `last` raise the same errors as `first`? Have you accidentally defined a `first` method anywhere in your Activity model?

Comment: Last, second, third all generate the same problem.